# In Corda, `No installed custom CorDapps.` on node's built-in webserver

Tags: corda

I have defined a CorDapp including an API. However, when I deploy the CorDapp and run my nodes, I see the following message at the webserver URL:

```
No installed custom CorDapps.
```

How can I get my node's built-in webserver to load my API?

Answer (score 0):

For the node's built-in webserver to load the API, you must do two things:

1. Create a `WebServerPluginRegistry` class that lists your API ([example](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/plugin/ExamplePlugin.kt#L12)):

   ```
   class MyWebPlugin : WebServerPluginRegistry {
       override val webApis = listOf(Function(::MyApi))
   }
   ```
2. List the fully-qualified class name of your web plugin under `resources/META-INF/services`, in a file called `net.corda.webserver.services.WebServerPluginRegistry` ([example](https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/net.corda.webserver.services.WebServerPluginRegistry))

   - List one fully-qualified plugin class name per line