# No installed Cordapp and localhost:1009/api returns a 404 via Http

Tags: api, plugins, webserver, http-status-code-404, corda

I'm trying to expose an API for a CorDapp and the functions are not displaying. 
I'm starting the nodes with the command ./runnodes. The Building process is successful. WebserverPluginRegistry is also implemented.
But if I try to connect to the Webserver with http://localhost:10009/ I get the Message "No  installed custom Cordapp".  I should only get this Message, if the Plugin is empty. But the Plugin is not empty!

If I try to Connect the node webserver endpoints with http://localhost:10009/api/XXX/me I get the Error Message:  HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing api/XXX/me  Reason: Not found

I know this is very vague but I cannot find any errors that indicate a specific area. Any help would be appreciated.

TransactionAPI.kt

```js
package com.YYY.api

import ……

val SERVICE_NAMES = listOf("Notary", "Network Map Service")

// This API is accessible from /api/XXX. All paths specified below are relative to it.
@Path("XXX")
class TransactionApi(private val rpcOps: CordaRPCOps) {
    private val myLegalName: CordaX500Name = rpcOps.nodeInfo().legalIdentities.first().name

    companion object {
        private val logger: Logger = loggerFor<TransactionApi>()
    }

    /**
     * Returns the node's name.
     */
    @GET
    @Path("me")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun whoami() = mapOf("me" to myLegalName)

    /**
     * Returns all parties registered with the [NetworkMapService]. These names can be used to look up identities
     * using the [IdentityService].
     */
    @GET
    @Path("peers")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getPeers(): Map<String, List<CordaX500Name>> {
        val nodeInfo = rpcOps.networkMapSnapshot()
        return mapOf("peers" to nodeInfo
                .map { it.legalIdentities.first().name }
                //filter out myself, notary and eventual network map started by driver
                .filter { it.organisation !in (SERVICE_NAMES + myLegalName.organisation)})
    }

    /**
     * Displays all XYZ that exist in the node's vault.
     */
    @GET
    @Path("XYZ")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun getXYZ() = rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<XYZ>().states


`
```

WebserverPluginRegistry

```js
# Register a ServiceLoader service extending from net.corda.webserver.services.WebServerPluginRegistry.
com.XXX.plugin.TransactionPlugin
```

TransactionPlugin

```js
package com.XXX.plugin

import com.XXX.api.TransactionApi
import net.corda.core.messaging.CordaRPCOps
import net.corda.webserver.services.WebServerPluginRegistry
import java.util.function.Function


class TransactionPlugin : WebServerPluginRegistry {

    // A list of classes that exposes web APIs.
    override val webApis:   List<Function<CordaRPCOps, out Any>> = listOf(Function(::TransactionApi))

    // A list of directories in the resources directory that will be served by Jetty under /web.
    override val staticServeDirs = mapOf(
            "XXX" to javaClass.classLoader.getResource("XXXWeb").toExternalForm()
    )

}
```

Comment: Are you able to share your code on GitHub? And have you registered your plugin like this? https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/net.corda.webserver.services.WebServerPluginRegistry

Comment: My plugin registered under:....cordapp\src\main\resources\META-INF.services\net.corda.webserver.services.WebServerPluginRegistry

Comment: Can you post the contents of the plugin file and `WebServerPluginRegistry` file?

Comment: Already Updated

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicated question. You can find the answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537592/in-corda-no-installed-custom-cordapps-on-nodes-built-in-webserver).

---

For any users prior to 2020, the Corda webserver is deprecated.

We now recommend users to use Spring boot. You can check [this project](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp) as an example.