# Corda node on GCP VM: No installed custom CordDapps

Tags: corda

I have the same problem as this post ([In Corda, `No installed custom CorDapps.` on node's built-in webserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537592/in-corda-no-installed-custom-cordapps-on-nodes-built-in-webserver)).

Here's what I did:
 1. I'm using the Java version of Tokens-SDK, it has a different folder structure from the examples mentioned in the solution of that post (i.e. clients, contracts, and workflows are 3 separate modules rather than one module).
 2. Here's my latest commit with the below mentioned changes:
    https://github.com/adelRestom/corda-tokens-api/commit/4fc730b352a184c3848ef2455e0fbb9e712a4e2b
 4. I created the class `ExamplePlugin` inside `clients` module
 5. I created the file `net.corda.webserver.services.WebServerPluginRegistry` inside `clients` module
 6. I updated `build.gradle` under the root folder of the project and added `cordapp project(":clients")` as a dependency (I'm not a gradle expert, but I assume that this should add this module to the jar file of the cordapp)
 7. I ran `./gradlew jar`
 8. I uploaded the jar file to `/opt/corda/cordapps` inside my google cloud VM
 9. I started the node using `run-corda.sh`
 10. I went to my browser and used the external IP address of my node with port 8080
 11. I get `No installed custom CordApps`

Can you please have a look at my repository and see what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my approach:
1. I generated the jars for contracts.jar and workflows.jar
2. I generated the SpringBoot webserver as a standalone jar (using `./gradlew bootJar`)
3. I started the node
4. I started the webserver
5. I was able to access my API end points

Answer (score 0):

After going through the repository, found that - 
Cordapp "clients" is not added in "task deployNodes" (see below)

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = false
        }
        cordapp("$tokens_release_group:tokens-contracts:$tokens_release_version")
        cordapp("$tokens_release_group:tokens-workflows:$tokens_release_version")
        cordapp("$tokens_release_group:tokens-money:$tokens_release_version")
        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
    }
```

Please check